# What's the format for teamcity VCS username?

Tags: teamcity

What's the correct format for the teamcity VCS username?

I tried `John Doe <john.doe@example.com>` But it still said

```
"We didn't find any VCS changes committed by you. Please make sure your VCS username settings are correct and you have permissions to view relevant projects."
```

Comment: What is the format in your VCS?

Comment: It is in my question "John Doe <john.doe@example.com>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using Git. In this case you can open settings of Git VCS root and check what is selected for Username style setting there. Note under this field should suggest you how VCS username should be configured.

Another option, is to make a checkin in VCS repository, wait till TeamCity detects it, then place mouse pointer over the username and click "It's me" link in the popup.